# How to make the child fit 100% of parent height with fixed view?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a fixed height of 20cm. Now, the inner page needs to have padding and position absolute needs to respect that padding.

How can I make the red box fill always what's left? The position absolute item needs to be always at the bottom no matter what.

It needs to have one class, and not 10classes with 10different heights like 58%, 45% etc...

If you check the codepen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/MqxvgW

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="page">

   <div class="image"></div>

   <div class="page-inner-default">
      <p>hello</p>
      <span class="pos-bot">Hi</span>
   </div>

</div>

<div class="page">

   <div class="image"></div>

   <h1>Heading</h1>

   <div class="page-inner-default">
      <p>hello</p>
     <span class="pos-bot">Hi</span>
   </div>

</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
   background: grey;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image {
   height: 250px;
   border: 1px solid green;
   background: green;;
}

.pos-bot {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}

.page {
   height: 20cm;
   background-color: white;
   width: 16cm;
   margin: 50px auto;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   position: relative;
}

.page-inner-default {
   position: relative;
   padding: 50px;
   height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
}

.image {

}
```

Comment: can you please clarify what your question is? Like what red box on the code pen? can you provide a class name to the div that is giving you problems?

Comment: 20cm? Why not em spaces or px?

Comment: There is only one red box on the codepen repeated twice. The class that has the red box on it, should fill the remaining space and not go over, like it goes now.

Comment: Because I'm doing a print version, so it needs to be in CM.

Comment: Your "red box" goes down off the screen... is this what you aim to fix?

Comment: Yes. it should fill the remaining height of the box, and not go over the div with class name page.

Comment: Does the 20cm have to stay as a requirement for your print?

Comment: Yes, technically it's an A4 but I put 20cm here so it fits in the screen.  I'm creating a catalogue pretty much, so it will get printent, so need to use cm and pts for the units.

Answer (score 0):

Give the .page{overflow:hidden} and remove the position relative from the .page-inner-default so the .pos-bot will be positioned to the closest relative and in this case it is the .page div

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
   background: grey;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image {
   height: 250px;
   border: 1px solid green;
   background: green;;
}

.pos-bot {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}

.page {
  overflow: hidden;
   height: 20cm;
   background-color: white;
   width: 16cm;
   margin: 50px auto;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   position: relative;
}

.page-inner-default {
   padding: 50px;
   min-height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="page">

     <div class="image"></div>

     <div class="page-inner-default">
        <p>hello</p>
        <span class="pos-bot">Hi</span>
     </div>

  </div>

  <div class="page">

     <div class="image"></div>

     <h1>Heading</h1>

     <div class="page-inner-default">
        <p>hello</p>
       <span class="pos-bot">Hi</span>
     </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Appriciate the answer, but overflow isn't going to work well when there is going to be padding at the bottom, where there is, but would need to add another div there and it's not going to work.. I'm looking for a clean solution just like you can do it with flexbox. Overflow doesn't matter, i already got that on my project. But the box needs to respect the padding, which means the 100% needs to be dynamic to the container. Overflow hidden just hides it, doesn't solve the problem.  Woff!